# How to dynamically arrange items in a GridLayout?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am printing some labels by looping through an array in `Nativescript-Vue`. I want the labels to arranged in a Grid. This is my template:

```
<GridLayout columns="auto,auto" rows="auto,auto">
  <label
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :text="item"
    :key="index"
  />
</GridLayout>
```

and this is the `items` array:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["A", "B","C","D","E","F"]
    }
  }
```

How do I dynamically assign the `row` and `column` attribute to `<label>` ?
I can do it manually but won't be able to loop through the array then.
I want it to be in order, like

A | B

C | D

E | F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use computed property to calculate the number of rows based on number of items. Then bind the row & col for each Label based on index.

```html
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ScrollView>
            <GridLayout columns="*,*" :rows="rows">
                <Label v-for="(item, index) in items" :text="item" :key="index"
                    :row="index / 2" :col="index % 2" class="h1"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                items: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
            };
        },
        computed: {
            rows: function() {
                const rows = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length / 2; i++) {
                    rows.push("auto");
                }
                return rows.join(",");
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=aChzbl)

Comment: Thanks Manoj! Just wanted to know one thing, I am quite new to Nativescript-Vue. Is this the best approach ? Will app performance suffer due to these extra calculations?

Comment: In terms of performance, GridLayout is best when you have minimal & known number of columns / rows. The more number of rows / columns, the more measurement process and less performance. You may also try RadListView with [ListViewGridLayout](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/listviewgridlayout.html) which is good for performance when you have to render a long list.